# Material UI - Customization of TextField with classnames created by class name generator

Tags: css, material-ui

I'm using Material UI V4 and trying to customise the TextField component as per the examples https://v4.mui.com/components/text-fields/#customized-inputs.

e.g. applying the following to the `root` class of the TextField to make the border color red.

```
root : {
    '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
      '& fieldset': {
        borderColor: 'red',
      },
   },
}
```

However, i am using the MUI class name generator, so in my app, all the MUI classnames are appended with a number e.g. `MuiOutlinedInput-root-735`, and so the styling I have is not applied to the TextField.

Is it the number being appended that is causing this not to be applied? Is there a way around this, so these styles can be applied even with the class name generator? Or perhaps an alternative way?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have nested themes? In v4, that is the only scenario that I would expect to cause the suffixed class names.

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60721323/how-reliable-are-mui-global-class-names-in-jss/60722943#60722943

Comment: @RyanCogswell Thanks for your answer - i do indeed have nested themes, and you are correct - that is the only part of the app with the suffixed class names and where i see this problem. I hadn't noticed that it was only in the nested themes before.

Using your suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60721323/how-reliable-are-mui-global-class-names-in-jss/60722943#60722943 helped resolve this.

Thank you!